# Inferring on an unknown number of function approximation

Tags: regression, machine-learning, inference

I want to ask whether a procedure to do the following job exists (or whether it makes sense for it to exist).

First, assume we have $k$ functions $f_1,...f_k$ that have the same domain and range. Then we have $n>k$ inputs $x_1,...,x_n$. For each $x_i$, we choose one $f_j$ according to a meta-function $F$ that takes $x_i$ and output $f_j$.

Then for each $x_i$ and the chosen $f_j$, we produce $y_i=f_j(x_i)+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is some noise. Therefore, we have $n$ pairs of $(x_i,y_i)$.

Now the question is, without knowing the number of functions $k$, is there a way to inferring what the $k$ functions and the meta-function $F$ can possibly be, without overfitting the data (i.e. generating too much and too specialized functions) and can do a pretty good job on predicting $y_{n+1}$ on a new $x_{n+1}$? Note the true answer is $y_{n+1}=(F(x_{n+1}))(x_{n+1})+\epsilon$ (where firstly $F$ outputs the function and then the function is applied to $x_{n+1}$).

So does this kind of inference exist or does it not make sense to do the job (maybe because it is too general to be possible)? I asked some people and they refer me to something called Chinese restaurant prior. I did not find it on Wikipedia. Instead, I read the the entry for Chinese restaurant process but did not see any relationship.

Edit: $x$ and $y$ can in general be high-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could re-phrase your question as an attempt to structure $F$ and find the individual $f_i$ functions that make the data most probable. it sounds like you're talking about a Hidden Markov Process:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is static and you know your meta-function $F$, you can try different value of $k$ and make use of model selection technique to find out the most likely value of $k$.

On the other hand (or in general), I think you can transform your problem as bayesian influence and try a MCMC-approach to solve your problem. [Peter Green (1995)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2337340) invented a technique to sample from the posterior distribution even if the dimension is unknown. Have a look on it, and I think textbook on computational statistics or Monte Carlo will discuss this too.